# Import/Export Javascript, dynamically created button event onclick(ES6)

Tags: javascript

Studying a bit of import and export in ES6 javascript, I had a question!

Until then, I created 3 `.js` files, where `Index.js` is the main file.

In this line `Element.BUTTON_ADD.onclick = createButton`; I create buttons dynamically.

And in this line `Element.BUTTON_CLICK.onclick = notify`; I want to trigger the onClick event for dynamically created buttons.

But it does not work!

After solving this problem, I will create other buttons dynamically with their respective `ID` and make the button access the `OnClick object` through `Action` and execute the `method sent`.

Example: `button.onclick = Action.addTab ('hello world')`;

How to do this?

**Index.js**

```
import * as Element from './Elements.js';
import Action from './onClick.js';

Element.BUTTON_ADD.onclick = createButton;

function createButton() {
    const button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    const text = document.createTextNode('ADD');    
    button.appendChild(text);
    button.setAttribute('class', 'click');
    Element.SIDEBAR.appendChild(button);
}

Element.BUTTON_CLICK.onclick = notify;

function notify() {
    alert('Hello World')
}
```

**Elements.js**

```
export const SIDEBAR = document.querySelector('#nav-left-item');
export const BUTTON_CLICK = document.querySelector('.click');
export const BUTTON_ADD = document.querySelector('.click-2');
```

**onClick.js**

```
const onClick = {
    addTab: function (data) {        
        console.log('added')
    },
    removeTab: function (data) {
        console.log('removed')
    },
};

export default onClick;
```

Comment: Do you use a build tool like Webpack or Parcel to combine the files or do you import each file as a module in your HTML? Could you add the relevant HTML to this piece of code?

Comment: I am not using any building hardware. I'm just using the HTML module. example: `<script type="module" src="../js/Index.js"></script>`

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: without error, in fact nothing happens, it's like I didn't click any button

Comment: Does logging `console.log(Element)` give you the correct object?

Comment: print MODULE, with the elements defined in Elements.js